# On a computer with .net 4.0 - Can one test that an application will run on .net 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I'm trying to port an application from .net 4.0 to .net 3.5. However, just changing it in Visual Studio is not enough, many references remain to .net 4.0. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709295/file-or-assembly-cant-be-found-after-changing-projects-net-target-framework)    for example.)

So - Is there a way to use my computer in order to test that this application will run on a computer with 3.5 only, even though my computer has .net 4 installed as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046089/force-an-application-to-run-under-specific-net-runtime-version

Comment: A .NET program that run on CLR v2.0.50727 cannot possibly load .NET 4 assemblies.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not saying you're wrong, of course; but why, then, does my application (which has `<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>` in **app.config**)  execute fine though it still has many 4.0 references such as in **Forms' resx files**:
`<assembly alias="System.Drawing" name="System.Drawing, Version=` **`4.0.0.0`** `, ... />`
And 
`<metadata name="..." type="System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing, Version=` **`4.0.0.0`** `, ... >`
?

Comment: Because your app doesn't read .resx files, the resgen.exe build tool does.  You ought to fix it, an ImageList will bomb I think.

Comment: @HansPassant I've posted a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610395/winforms-resx-file-referencing-4-0-0-0-works-fine-despite-targeting-clr-2-0-w .

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

First of all this is not provided by MS. Features are backward-compatible. If they would be forward-compatible, then you wouldn't have this question asked and we wouldn't have progress. =D

There is no backward project converter as well.

Secondly, for a good test, you really want clean environment, without case to have references to assemblies which are not installed.

Your only bet is either other PC or VM. Installing and using [Windows XP](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7) one is pretty dawn easy. Go straight for it.

Answer (score -2):

OK, Apologies. Now, I understand better.

You can simultaneously install multiple .net versions, enable/disable them in the control panel.

See: [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

HTH